# @override annotation in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know there are many people asking the same question (and many answering it), but none of their answers are helping me.

I always get @override annotation errors if I'm anonymously implementing a method from an interface.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override //  <-- **this will give error message**
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Menu menu = MainMenu.listMenu.get(i);


            Tabs.setCurrentTab(menu.pos + 1); 
        }
    });
```

I am developing my android application in a team. My team are using IDEA whilst I am using eclipse.
My team never get this error. Could it be eclipse's bug?

Our java version is the same, 1.6.
My eclipse version is 3.7.

The error is :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must override a superclass 
 method
- implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick
```

Can anyone suggest someting that could be done to remove this error?

EDIT : 
more information, i would not get error in this case :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            ...
            }

            Menu menu = Menu.getListMenu().get(position);

            if (menu != null){
               ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          ...
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this kind of error before and it's to do with the Eclipse configuration. I guess where you point your JDK or the build path. I don't remember exactly, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. But it's something on this direction.

Comment: Did you let Eclipse implement the method onItemClick itself ? I remember I had this errors when I was writing direclty or pasting some code of overriding methods.

Comment: @Budius do you mean Error/Warnings, under Preference/Java/Compiler?

Comment: @AlexisCartier my team write it in IDEA, i update it from SVN, so i am sorry, i can't tell if it were pasted or wrote directly.

Comment: No. I reckon it's what Rich said on his answer. I read you said it didn't work, but try cleaning the project/restarting eclipse.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC i'm sorry, that not work.

Comment: clean and restart not helping too.

Answer (score 10):

I have had this problem several times when importing a project from existing code.  The JDK compliance level for some reason defaults to Java 1.5 even though you have 1.6 installed on your machine.  If this is the case, right click on your project in the Eclipse package explorer, select Properties, select the Java Compiler section, and set the JDK Compliance level to 1.6

Comment: i'm sorry, i am sure that's not the case. i've set this many times. still not working. even if i set it while project specific setting enabled.

Comment: Do you have Project > Build Automatically selected as well as ALL compliance level settings set to 1.6 under Java Compiler?

Comment: Also, if all of these check out and you still have a problem, right-click your project, select Android > Fix Project Properties.  There may be some project specific settings that are not getting to appropriate defaults because you have imported source from a different IDE

Comment: Yes, it is autobuild. And i have triple check the compliance level setting.

Comment: I did fix the project too... It's been a month since we start the project. I am start to think i will use idea from now on..

Comment: I had the exact same issue - Override for onItemClick when implementing the OnItemClickListener inline - and this was the answer for me.  +1 from me.